# How to resolve the “Expected a type” error in @class in ios

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

Here is my code. It showing 'Expected a type' error in first line.

```
@class RateView;

@protocol RateViewDelegate <NSObject>;

- (void)rateView:(RateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(float)rating;
@end

@interface RateView : UIView
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@class RateView;

@protocol RateViewDelegate<NSObject>   /* Remove Semi colon after declaring the protocol,seems the mistake is here only! */

-(void)rateView:(RateView *)rateView ratingDidChange:(float)rating;

@end

@interface RateView : UIView

@end
```

HTH! :)

Comment: This kind of silly mistakes were very hard to find :p